# AEM - Apply separate styles to authoring view and publishing view for component

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

I'm using Adobe Experience Manager and i need to apply separate styles to authoring view and publishing view for component. The reason for this is I have some JS that changes the layout of the component at desktop size, however in authoring mode this means the component is no longer usable or fully visible.

So far I have:

- looked in Adobe Forums for a similar question
- tried to add some styles within html file based on the condition of edit mode being true:

  ```
   <sly data-sly-test.author="${wcmmode.edit}"><style><!--my code--></style></sly>
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing inline styles based on the edit mode, better way would be to define a separate client library and add that client library on your pages only in edit mode. Let's say, you have a component - "Custom Component" which has the class as - "custom-comp".

```
<div class="custom-component">
    <!-- your custom component html code goes here -->
</div>
```

So I am assuming you would already have defined some CSS for this component in the project client library that should be loaded on your pages already. To style it different in author mode, you can try following steps -

1. In your page.html, define a special class which will identify whether your page is being loaded in Author or in Publish. Something like below -

   < body class="${wcmmode.edit || wcmmode.design ? 'authoring-mode' : ''}">
2. Using above line of code, your pages will now have a special class - "authoring-mode" only when you open the page in Author. But when you open page in publish, this class won't appear which is exactly what you want here.
3. Now, you need to define a new client library in your code which will have CSS and JS files and you need to load this new client library in your customheaderlibs. Again this client library needs to be added only in author mode.
4. Write custom CSS rules for your custom component using the combination of two class names - "authoring-mode" and component class name - "custom-component".
5. Test your changes in author mode and publish mode.

Comment: Going to give this a try - looks promising! Will check back and thumbs up your answer if this is the fix. Thank you

Comment: @EmmaEarlKent there's an [Adobe tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/pl/experience-manager/kt/sites/using/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/part3.html) that explains this use case in a little more detail.

Comment: Sure @EmmaEarlKent!